# Internationalisation-correct way to select network adapter to bind to

Tags: windows, internationalization, ndis

I have an application which needs to bind to a "Microsoft Loopback Adapter".  I can enumerate all the network devices and perform a string match on the friendly name, but of course this will fail on international Windows variants.

What is the correct way to identify the right network adapter?

Comment: Any reason why you can't bind to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: We're not using it to loopback... the interface has a 169.254.x.x IP address, and then another NDIS driver allows us to capture the packets as they go down the stack and push them out of a different interface.

Comment: When I say different interface, I mean a non-Ethernet interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to worry about hard-coding the user-facing string.  Not only is localization a problem, but the string actually changed in Windows 7.  So "Microsoft Loopback Adapter" won't even match on an en-US version of a recent OS.

The best invariant you can look for is the hardware ID of the network interface, which is `*MSLOOP`, including the literal asterisk.

One approach is to use `INetCfg`.  The gist is to find an `INetCfgComponent` where its [`GetId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547870(v=vs.80)) method returns the string `"*msloop"`.  Once you know the matching component, you can query its GUID from [`GetInstanceGuid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547877(v=vs.85).aspx).  That GUID uniquely identifies the NIC in many networking APIs.  If you need to convert the GUID to some other identifier (like ifAlias or NET_LUID), then you can use [`GetIfTable2Ex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814413(v=vs.85).aspx) or related to map the GUID to the other identifier.

In pseudocode, that might resemble:

```
CoInitializeEx
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CNetCfg, 0, CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&netcfg));
netcfg->Initialize(0)
netcfg->EnumComponents(GUID_DEVCLASS_NET, &enumerator)
while (S_OK == enumerator->Next(1, &component, 0))
    component->GetId(&id)
    if (id case-insensitive-match "*msloop")
        component->GetInstanceGuid(result)
        print "Windows loopback adapter: " + result
```

If you have the luxury of running on Windows 8 or later, this can be executed quite easily in PowerShell:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where ComponentID -eq '*msloop'
```

From there, you can peel off any interesting properties, or even go straight to its IP address:

```
Get-NetAdapter | 
    Where ComponentID -eq '*msloop' | 
    Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 |
    fl IPAddress
```